# set default "open with" on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11

With the changes to the UI I am unable to figure out how to change the default programs that show up when I right click to open a file.

[image]

I can of course click "Show More Options" to open that pane, but I would like to replace "Open in Windows Terminal" with "Open in Visual Studio Code".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The new Context menu is itself context sensitive and changes according to the operation you are doing.

For Production and Insider version 22000.282 and 346, There is not a native way to permanently change the context menu to what you want, but I think what you want is already there.

Right click on a File and Open With appears in the Context menu. True for Windows 11 Pro Insider and Production - I have both.

[image: Context Menu]

**Follow up:  Selection from The Windows Club**

[Windows Club Article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-customize-and-use-windows-11-explorer)

> Currently, you cannot change the context menu in Windows 11. Earlier,
> it was possible with a few tweaks in the Registry Editor which are
> curtailed by Microsoft in the latest Windows 11 updates. We have to
> wait and see if we can get an option to change it in the later
> versions of Windows 11.

This is just to belt and suspender my earlier post.

Since Windows 11 is new, this may or may not change sometime down the road.

Comment: in windows 10 I set up my context menu so that when i right clicked it gave me the option to open with vscode on the first page... So if this is an 'unfixable' thing that's a bit of a bummer because the workflow has gone from *right click* and then *click* on vscode to *right click* *show more options* *click* on vscode.

Comment: I am not sure about specialty things, but context on regular files work like I showed in one click with no need for more options. If you are using specialty files and constructions then you will need two clicks natively - especially because built in context is itself always changing.

Comment: @yodama - Forget about what was possible on Windows 10 and previous versions.  The Windows 11 context menu is completely different.  What was possible in previous versions is not necessary still possible on Windows 11.

Comment: that's fair! good to know that this is just not available and not that I'm missing something.

Comment: So I think I have answered your question quite fully here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it (adding this line so the AI does not qualify my answer as robotic):

Hold shift button when you do right-click and the "Show more options" menu will show instead.
LE+

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).